# Change material property depending on pose position

Tags: materials, bones

I'm new to blender and know very little about animation, but I do know a bit about shading. I'm trying to practice my shading skills with a blender exercise. I recently downloaded a free piano file at https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/free-obj-mode-piano/941702. It's rigged and everything, and I cut it down to just a few notes for the purposes of the exercise.

I have a texture that colours a rainbow across a distance of keys using the following node setup, and using a mix shader I've combined it with the regular off-white key colour.
[image]

[image]

That way, when I adjust the fac of the mix shader, I can transition between white and rainbow.

[image]

Ok. Here's what I'm trying to do. The model I downloaded comes with a few bones already attached to the keys.

[image]

What nodes can I connect to the fac of the mix shader that will allow the keys to transition between colour and white depending on whether they have been pressed (the associated bones rotated).

[image]

I know that I could create a separate texture for each key and animate them individually, but the whole point is that I'm trying to learn new things.
So is there any setup that can take the rotation data of the associated bone and use that as the fac?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I've since added a driver that can change the value of the fac based on the rotation of a bone (yippee!). However, I still don't know how to differentiate keys based on the bones they should be attached to, so I've just got one bone that controls the colour for all the keys.

[image]